# How to select a row element value from Oracle APEX 4 Classic Report (row element from a table tags)

Tags: jquery, row, oracle-apex, html-table

Here is the challenge..

I have a classic report based on SQL on Region 1 in Oracle APEX 4

The report (Report1) is structured like

```
    DATE_COL(this column will be hidden) or even the whole region can be hidden)
Row1    12-01-2001
Row2    11-01-2001
Row3    10-01-2001
```

I want to select the value of DATE_COL of Row1 which is Date1 and assigned that to a label of an ITEM which can be on the same page or another page..

The ITEM say for example is P_ITEM whose name will be displayed as 12-01-2001 on the screen

So, essentially I want to select a Row1 element of report of column DATE_COL and use that as label name

Then I wan to select Row2 element of the DATE_COL which is DATE2 and assigned to the col1 label of another report on the same page which is Report2 and will look like this

```
 <a href = "www.google.com"> 11-01-2001 </a> (this name is coming from report 1 of DATE_COL of Row2 element) also it has link

Row1   100
Row2   200
```

Please guide me how to accomplish this one.

The example html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table id="report_R124146326020103259" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="1" summary="">
<tbody>

<tr>

<td>

<table class="report-standard" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0" summary="">

<tbody>

<tr>
 <th id="DATE1" class="header" align="left">DATE1</th>
 <th id="DATE2" class="header" align="left">DATE2</th>
 <th id="DATE3" class="header" align="left">DATE3</th>
 <th id="DATE4" class="header" align="left">DATE4</th>
 <th id="DATE5" class="header" align="left">DATE5</th>
</tr>

<tr class="highlight-row">
 <td class="data" headers="DATE1">12-01-2001</td>
 <td class="data" headers="DATE2">11-01-2001</td>
 <td class="data" headers="DATE3">10-01-2001</td>
 <td class="data" headers="DATE4">09-01-2001</td>
 <td class="data" headers="DATE5">08-01-2001</td>
</tr>

<tr class="highlight-row">
 <td class="data" headers="DATE1">10-01-2001</td>
 <td class="data" headers="DATE2">09-01-2001</td>
 <td class="data" headers="DATE3">08-01-2001</td>
 <td class="data" headers="DATE4">12-01-2001</td>
 <td class="data" headers="DATE5">11-01-2001</td>
</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I guess JQuery can be used to accomplish, but not sure, how the selector need to use.

Thanks,
--CP

EDIT 1

I created following script based on Tom's Jquery selector which does selects the row element. However the following script which I ran in W3Schools html editor didn't select the row element, which I put in Test function. The test function which I am calling in "A tag" didn't produce any results. However the other function which is WelcomeMessage did produce the result. Can anybody help me identify the error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function test(i) { 
       var ab = $("#report_DT tr:eq(i) td.data[headers='DATE1']").text();
       document.write(ab);
    }

    function welcomeMessage()
    {
      document.write("Welcome to Henley's Department Store!");
    }
    </script>

    </head>


    <body>

    <table id="report_DT" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="1" summary="">
    <tbody>

    <tr>

    <td>

    <table class="report-standard" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0" summary="">

    <tbody>

    <tr>
     <th id="DATE1" class="header" align="left">DATE1</th>
     <th id="DATE2" class="header" align="left">DATE2</th>
     <th id="DATE3" class="header" align="left">DATE3</th>
     <th id="DATE4" class="header" align="left">DATE4</th>
     <th id="DATE5" class="header" align="left">DATE5</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="highlight-row">
     <td class="data" headers="DATE1">12-01-2001</td>
     <td class="data" headers="DATE2">11-01-2001</td>
     <td class="data" headers="DATE3">10-01-2001</td>
     <td class="data" headers="DATE4">09-01-2001</td>
     <td class="data" headers="DATE5">08-01-2001</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="highlight-row">
     <td class="data" headers="DATE1">10-01-2001</td>
     <td class="data" headers="DATE2">09-01-2001</td>
     <td class="data" headers="DATE3">08-01-2001</td>
     <td class="data" headers="DATE4">12-01-2001</td>
     <td class="data" headers="DATE5">11-01-2001</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>

    </td>

    </tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>

    <a href ="default.asp">  

    <div> <Script Language="JavaScript">
                         test(i);
                      </Script>
                 </div>


    </a>


    <a href ="default.asp">  

    <div> <Script Language="JavaScript">
                         welcomeMessage();
                      </Script>
                 </div>


    </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can anybody spot the error why test function is not retrieving the desired result?

Comment: looks cryptic. please make an example of how the result should look like

Comment: I cannot understand your question at all. Is the HTML from report 1? If so, where is the HTML from report 2?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, the html is of Report 1 and eventhough the Report 1 example has just one column and three, the html has one 1 row and 5 column. However, it doesn't matter how the report 1 is structure, because the core objective is to select the value from the report 1 table and then assign to the label of an item or another report's column label. the example of how the report 2 looks like is already there in the question. To Mark, for example sake, the the html of report 1 and change the data of date values with some numbers.. and you get report 2 html. please let me know if not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you want to assign your region a static id (edit region > attributes > static id)

then use

```
$("#yourregionid tr:eq("+ rownumber_you_need +") td.data[headers='"+ header_id +"']").text()
```

Take note that :eq uses a zero-index based system, so row 0 would be the one with the headers, and row 1 your first row with actual data.
Replace header_id with the header of the column you need data from. In your example:

```
$("#yourregionid tr:eq(1) td.data[headers='DATE1']").text()
$("#yourregionid tr:eq(2) td.data[headers='DATE2']").text()
```

Edit:

```
<a href="javascript:test(1);">click for a test</a>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function test(i) { 
   var ab = $("#report_DT tr:eq(i) td.data[headers='DATE1']").text();
   alert(ab);
}; 
</script>
```

Edit 2:
So if you want to actively manipulate the table headers for your second report:
- assign a static region id to your report region 2
- create a dynamic action for the "After refresh" event, for a region (your second region). This is necessary to allow pagination on your region while still maintaining the altered headers.
- for true action, select an execute javascript code:

```
$("#report2staticid th").each(function(index){
   var linktext, newlink;
   if(index==0){
      linktext = $("report1staticid tr:eq(1) td.data[headers='DATE1']").text();
      newlink = $("<a />").attr("href", "www.google.com").text(linktext);
   } else if(index==1){
      //something for header 2
   } else if(index==2){
      //andsoforth
   };
   $(this).html(newlink);
});
```

This loops over each TH element in your second report, and changes the html content of each th: we put a new A-tag in each one.

Edit 3:
You made some mistakes in your implementation:

```
function test(i) { 
   var ab = $("#report_DT tr:eq(i) td.data[headers='DATE1']").text();
   document.write(ab);
}
```

should be

```
function test(i) { 
   var ab = $("#report_DT table.report-standard tr:eq("+i+") td.data[headers='DATE1']").text();
   document.write(ab);
}
```

i is an input parameter, and you need to concatenate it into the selector string.

Your HTML script tag is also wrong. You call test and provide "i" to it. What is "i"? Nowhere is it defined. Provide a value. (Remember, this is the rownumber.)

```
<Script Language="JavaScript">test(1);</Script>
```

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function test(i) {
         var ab = $("#report_DT table.report-standard tr:eq("+i+") td.data[headers='DATE1']").text();
        document.write(ab);
      }
      function welcomeMessage()     {
      document.write("Welcome to Henley's Department Store!");
      }
      </script>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="report_DT" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="1" summary="">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <table class="report-standard" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border=
                  "0" summary="">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <th id="DATE1" class="header" align="left">
                              DATE1
                           </th>
                           <th id="DATE2" class="header" align="left">
                              DATE2
                           </th>
                           <th id="DATE3" class="header" align="left">
                              DATE3
                           </th>
                           <th id="DATE4" class="header" align="left">
                              DATE4
                           </th>
                           <th id="DATE5" class="header" align="left">
                              DATE5
                           </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="highlight-row">
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE1">
                              12-01-2001
                           </td>
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE2">
                              11-01-2001
                           </td>
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE3">
                              10-01-2001
                           </td>
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE4">
                              09-01-2001
                           </td>
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE5">
                              08-01-2001
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="highlight-row">
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE1">
                              10-01-2001
                           </td>
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE2">
                              09-01-2001
                           </td>
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE3">
                              08-01-2001
                           </td>
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE4">
                              12-01-2001
                           </td>
                           <td class="data" headers="DATE5">
                              11-01-2001
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table><a href="default.asp">
      <div>
         <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
         test(1);
         </script>
      </div>
      </a>
      <a href="default.asp">
      <div>
         <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
         welcomeMessage();                       
         </script>
      </div>
      </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is helpful, as I am able to select the column value. Now, using this logic. I created a JS function. <script type="text/javascript">
function test(i) {
var ab = $("#report_DT tr:eq(i) td.data[headers='DATE1']").text();
return ab;
}; </script>
and then calling this function in the anchor element to assign a label to the anchor based on the input. here the <a> tag logic
 <a href ="www.google.com"> javascript:"test(1)" </a> . I ran this in html editor but it is not working.. any idea what am I doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: See my edited post. You might need to clear this up though: is it your intention to add 'links' (buttons, a-tags, column links...) to each row? It just seems like that will be the follow-up comment about how to handle your row indexes then.

Comment: No, there is no intention to add link to every row of the column. The intention is to add link only to column header and the label name will be generated from the other report column value. e.g. Report 2 has a column whose label will be "11-01-2001" which will come from report 1 column1 row2 value as described in example. and there will be a link which when clicked will take to another page. however in example I just put "www.google.com", so the lable name should come from javascript function and only column header has link. hope it is much more clear now. Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: See edit1 of my post. That should help you a bit but may need some debug, and some altering on your part to make it fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I will apply your edit2 in my application. My question is how come the code that I put in edit 1 of my question, which I was testing in HTML editor of W3Schools not working. can you please look into the html that I added to my question as edit and provide me your inputs.. thanks a lot..

Comment: Take a look at my 3rd edit. You made some mistakes in your implementation of the function. (and when your question is answered, don't forget to tick the correct answer ;) )

Comment: Hi Tom, I did apply the changes that you suggested in edit 3, but still not working, I also tried in single quotation and with + sign at in front only and back only. different combination, but still no change. I tested in www.w3schools.org html editor. do you think there could be any other issue.?

Comment: oh - i only now noticed this: your table is wrapped in another table, meaning that tr:eq(1) will not get you the row you desire. The selector takes the wrapping table, and then looks for the second occuring TR element in that element. Sure enough, there is such an element, but this will be the TR with the TH's in it. To help this, you need to actually select the report-table: `var ab = $("#report_DT table.report-standard tr:eq("+i+") td.data[headers='DATE1']").text();` I altered my post to reflect this aswell.

Comment: I did apply this change, but still no difference. the selector $("#report_DT table.report-standard tr:eq("+i+") works when I run this in firebug for my application, however, It doesn't work on the html that I created and which is in the question. I created html page and saved as .html on my desktop for the above code, which I opened in firefox, I can see the table but when i ran the selector in firebug console it didn't work. I am getting null value. Strange, I presume there is some other issue as well. Do you see any other factor?, thanks a lot for your help so far. I will click your answer.

Comment: I added the full html code in my answer. This is the code i took from your question (your edited-in code), with the added fixes. I ran this code in the w3schools html editor, i ran it in firefox, and i ran it in IE. They all work! See if you can spot a difference.

Comment: I see, I was trying in html editor in W3Schools, when I opened Jquery based editor in W3shcools it worked.. thanks a lot. it works like a gem..